# How to get Async to run thread in background?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am pulling around 1500 data plots and adding them to overlays for an map view. I want to run this in another thread while the rest of my program finishes starting up. I would like a progress spinner to spin only on the map portion while its loading the data plot points.

I have searched and found what I need, but Im not sure how to implement it and where in my code to put it.

1. What would I put in the params
2. Does this go in another class or in my main oncreate method.
3. When would I call the methods?

   ```
   private class UpdateFeedTask extends AsyncTask<MyActivity, Void, Void> {

   private ProgressDialog mDialog;

   protected void onPreExecute() {
       Log.d(TAG, " pre execute async");
       mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this,"Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);

   }

   protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
       Log.d(TAG, " progress async");     
   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(MyActivity... params) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return null;
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       Log.d(TAG, " post execute async");
       mDialog.dismiss();
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I actually am not a hundred percent sure what you currently understand about `AsyncTask`s so this may be a little some stuff you already know but bear with me.

"Does this go in another task or in my onCreate method?":
`AsyncTask` is a class which you are supposed to subclass to do what you need, it is not a piece of code which can inlined in your `onCreate`. You could make an anonymous `AsyncTask` class in your onCreate, but usually you want it as either a private internal class or its own class entirely.

As for when you call the methods; you don't they are lifecycle events.

`onPreExecute()` is called on the UI thread just before starting the background work and is a place to do things such as modify components to show progress, or throw up a dialog.

`doInBackground(Params...)` is the main method which runs in the background on another thread, do your work here. **Do not try to modify UI here**

onPostExecute(Result) is when your task has finished and is run on the UI thread again. This is where you should handle your UI update.

You only call `execute(Params..)`, which will start the `AsyncTask`, passing the objects you put as the params into the `doInBackground(Params...)` method of the task. So the answer as to what to put as params is whatever you need to have access to in `doInBackground(Params...)`.

That should be a decent overview for your needs but you should really check out [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

**1. What would I put in the params**
It depends. The First parameter is what the task will take in. 
The last generic is what it will return.

**2.Does this go in another class or in my main oncreate method.** You call the execute method when the you want the task to run. The implementation can be in the Activity class or in a different .java file.

**3.When would I call the methods?**
You only call the execute method. That will make the task run in the background. Then the task will call onPostExecute when it is done.

Here is an example

```
private class UpdateFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, DataReturnType> {
    @Override
    protected DataReturnType doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        //Get data from URL

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ReturnDataType result) {
        //Do something with result
    }
}
```

Then call the task using the `execute("http://foo.com")`

Also add `android:configChanges=true` to the Activity in the manifest. This will make sure that the activity is not killed when the task is still running in the background. Otherwise the task will finish and report back to a null Activity unless you tell the task to callback the new activity.

Comment: So I traced my program the progress bar comes up but it wont execute any code such as
    setContentView(R.layout.maptabview);
  mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
  Log.v("","Runnnnnn");
  mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  mapController = mapView.getController();
  mapController.setZoom(4);

it will only execute the log.v if I start off with that.

Comment: You don't want to put any reference to a UI component into the Task (because it could be killed). I extended a Overlay and kept a reference to that in my Task. Then at the end of the task add the Overlay to the list of map overlays.

Answer (score 0):

To start the AsyncTask, you simply go

```
(new UpdateFeedTask()).execute(activityInstance);
```

It can go where ever you want it, though where you put it might limit access to the variables and objects you want to interact with. E.g. private internal class will have access to them while an entirely new class might not have as easy of an access.

```
doInBackground(MyActivity... params)
```

is where the parameter you passed into the `execute()` function will go, and you can access it via `params[0]`.

You should not call any methods in the AsyncTask class, besides `execute()`.

Comment: So I traced my program the progress bar comes up but it wont execute any code such as setContentView(R.layout.maptabview); mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView); Log.v("","Runnnnnn"); mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); mapController = mapView.getController(); mapController.setZoom(4); it will only execute the log.v if I start off with that